# upload an view image

Tags: c#, asp.net

Problem is i set the image url clicking lnkFV link button. but image not viewed on the page.
source

```
<tr>
     <td style="width: 160px; height: 15px">
         <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Style Front View">
         </asp:Label>
    </td>
     <td style="width: 222px; height: 15px">
          <asp:FileUpload id="filFrontView" runat="server">
          </asp:FileUpload>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 72px; height: 15px">
           <asp:LinkButton id="lnkFV" runat="server" OnClick="lnkFV_Click">
           View image</asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
         <asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server">
         </asp:Image></td>
  </tr>
```

asp code

```
protected void lnkFV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // new Help().Perform("Do you really want to proceed");
    try
    {
        file = Path.GetFileName(filFrontView.PostedFile.FileName);
       // file = Path.GetFileName(filFrontView.PostedFile.FileName);
        tempF = "F:\\Visual Studio 2005\\User\\temp\\" + file;
        temp = "~\\temp\\" + file;
        filFrontView.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(temp));
       // filFrontView.SaveAs(temp);
        string filePath = MapPath(temp);
        Image1.ImageUrl = tempF; 
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Ajax?  Is the file getting saved properly?  Are you getting an exception?  More detail is needed.

Comment: Is there any exception generated?

Comment: no exception. above code set the image url to the image1.but image not viewed. no exceptions. dont no why. image1 visible= true. if you can please help me.

Comment: May I ask what purpose the empty catch block is serving?

Answer (score 3):

Is this your problem?

```
tempF = "F:\\Visual Studio 2005\\User\\temp\\" + file;
// ... other stuff ...
Image1.ImageUrl = tempF;
```

It looks like you're setting the ImageUrl property to a string that's the local machine path to the image.  That's not going to work for people who aren't running their browser on the web server.  ImageUrl should probably be a relative path to the image, relative to the current page or to the virtual root of your web app.

What does the HTML source look like when your page is finally rendered?

You are also going to have to make sure to saved that image to a folder that is web-accessible.  It seems unlikely that the `F:\Visual Studio 2005\User\temp` folder is really going to fit the bill here.  In general, I think you'll want to work with relative paths instead of hardcoding a path like that, if you want your web-uploaded images to be visible on your site.